# Sessions not persisting

Tags: jsp, session, cookies, session-cookies, sessionid

I've got a simple bit of JSP which displays the ID of the current session. It should be generated when the session is created, and afterwards it should persist until the browser closes.

Here is the code that should do as I have described:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
Your session ID is :  <%=session.getId()%>
</body>
</html>
```

In Chrome, <strike>FF Private Browsing Mode</strike> and IE, the session is maintained and the output stays as something like:

> Your session ID is : CF29941D705A657A91EBD44A35D68803

However in Firefox normal mode, every time you refresh the page, a new ID is generated.

Can anybody help me solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you get a new session ID everytime in a particular webbrowser, then that can only mean that the particular webbrowser has cookies disabled for the particular domain. Check and fix the webbrowser's settings.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions/cookies do not seem to be maintained on localhost. This may be why the code wasn't working.